# Showing two of the four choices as the same country

Tags: vb.net

```
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form1.Load

        Dim Flagimageurl(6) As String ' creating the flag image url array'
        Flagimageurl(0) = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/uk-lgflag.gif"
        Flagimageurl(1) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg/800px-Flag_of_France.svg.png"
        Flagimageurl(2) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/05/Flag_of_Brazil.svg/720px-Flag_of_Brazil.svg.png"
        Flagimageurl(3) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Spain.svg/750px-Flag_of_Spain.svg.png"
        Flagimageurl(4) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/1235px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png"
        Flagimageurl(5) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Flag_of_Russia_%28Kremlin.ru%29.svg/1024px-Flag_of_Russia_%28Kremlin.ru%29.svg.png"


        Dim CountryNames(6) As String 'creating the country names array'
        CountryNames(0) = "United Kingdom"
        CountryNames(1) = "France"
        CountryNames(2) = "Brazil"
        CountryNames(3) = "Spain"
        CountryNames(4) = "United States of America (USA)"
        CountryNames(5) = "Russia"

        flag.ImageUrl = Flagimageurl(6 * Rnd()) 'Choosing a random flag'
        RadioButton1.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd()) 'Randomly picks the country according to the CountryNames array'
        RadioButton2.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())  ' with random * 6 you get blanks so you need to use random * 5'
        RadioButton3.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())
        RadioButton4.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())

        If RadioButton1.Text = RadioButton2.Text Then 'Makes sure that the radiobuttons don't show duplicate answers'
            RadioButton2.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())
        End If

        If RadioButton2.Text = RadioButton1.Text Then
            RadioButton1.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())
        End If

        If RadioButton3.Text = RadioButton1.Text Or RadioButton3.Text = RadioButton2.Text Then
            RadioButton3.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())
        End If

        If RadioButton4.Text = RadioButton1.Text Or RadioButton2.Text = RadioButton3.Text Then
            RadioButton4.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that when I run the code two of the four answers are the same. Or the other thing that it does is it does not always have the correct answer for that flag.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but FYI `Dim Flagimageurl(6) As String` creates an array that holds _**7 items**_. To create one that holds 6 items either do: `Dim Flagimageurl(5) As String` or for better readability/understanding: `Dim Flagimageurl(6 - 1) As String` -- **NOTE:** This behaviour is specific to VB.NET only.

Comment: depending how you generate the random number some functions are besed off the system time and thus you can get similar results

Comment: mederic I don't understand

Comment: @Mederic : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 4):

First I would consider using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Dim countries As New Dictionary(Of String, String) _
    From {{"United Kingdom", "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/uk-lgflag.gif"},
          {"France", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg/800px-Flag_of_France.svg.png"},
          {"Brazil", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/05/Flag_of_Brazil.svg/720px-Flag_of_Brazil.svg.png"},
          {"Spain", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Spain.svg/750px-Flag_of_Spain.svg.png"},
          {"United States of America (USA)", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/1235px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png"},
          {"Russia", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Flag_of_Russia_%28Kremlin.ru%29.svg/1024px-Flag_of_Russia_%28Kremlin.ru%29.svg.png"}}
```

I would then use the [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) class, add the item to another `Dictionary` and remove the item from the current `Dictionary` so it cannot be used again. I'm also looping through the six `RadioButton` controls to reduce code but you could separate out and do each `RadioButton` in turn. This would depend on your design:

```
Dim countriesSelected As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Dim countryRandom As New Random
For Each rd As RadioButton In Me.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
    Dim nextRandom As Integer = countryRandom.Next(countries.Count)
    rd.Text = countries.Keys(nextRandom)
    countriesSelected.Add(countries.Keys(nextRandom), countries.Values(nextRandom))
    countries.Remove(countries.Keys(nextRandom))
Next

Dim flagRandom As New Random
flag.ImageUrl = countriesSelected.Values(flagRandom.Next(countriesSelected.Count))
```

Output:

[image: Output]

For if you want to separate out here is the code:

```
Dim countryRandom As New Random
Dim nextRandom As Integer = countryRandom.Next(countries.Count)
RadioButton1.Text = countries.Keys(nextRandom)
countriesSelected.Add(countries.Keys(nextRandom), countries.Values(nextRandom))
countries.Remove(countries.Keys(nextRandom))

nextRandom = countryRandom.Next(countries.Count)
RadioButton2.Text = countries.Keys(nextRandom)
countriesSelected.Add(countries.Keys(nextRandom), countries.Values(nextRandom))
countries.Remove(countries.Keys(nextRandom))

nextRandom = countryRandom.Next(countries.Count)
RadioButton3.Text = countries.Keys(nextRandom)
countriesSelected.Add(countries.Keys(nextRandom), countries.Values(nextRandom))
countries.Remove(countries.Keys(nextRandom))

nextRandom = countryRandom.Next(countries.Count)
RadioButton4.Text = countries.Keys(nextRandom)
countriesSelected.Add(countries.Keys(nextRandom), countries.Values(nextRandom))
countries.Remove(countries.Keys(nextRandom))
```

You can see why I chose to loop through the `RadioButton` controls. It's much simpler to read and maintain.

---

If you really must use an `Array` as you've said in your comments then I'll try and do that for you. The code is ugly and probably harder to understand, at least in my opinion but it should give you what you are after.

First change `(6)` to `(5)` as this will create 6 items. An `Array` is zero based so 0 is the first item not 1. The indexes in both of the arrays must be identical so that we pick the right flag at the end.

```
Dim Flagimageurl(5) As String ' creating the flag image url array'
Flagimageurl(0) = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/uk-lgflag.gif"
Flagimageurl(1) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg/800px-Flag_of_France.svg.png"
Flagimageurl(2) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/05/Flag_of_Brazil.svg/720px-Flag_of_Brazil.svg.png"
Flagimageurl(3) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Spain.svg/750px-Flag_of_Spain.svg.png"
Flagimageurl(4) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/1235px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png"
Flagimageurl(5) = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Flag_of_Russia_%28Kremlin.ru%29.svg/1024px-Flag_of_Russia_%28Kremlin.ru%29.svg.png"

Dim CountryNames(5) As String 'creating the country names array'
CountryNames(0) = "United Kingdom"
CountryNames(1) = "France"
CountryNames(2) = "Brazil"
CountryNames(3) = "Spain"
CountryNames(4) = "United States of America (USA)"
CountryNames(5) = "Russia"
```

I have created a separate `Array` in an attempt to hold the countries that have been selected.

```
Dim selectedCountries(3) As String
```

Still use the `Random` class and loop through the `RadioButton` controls only this time we have to also loop through `selectedCountries` to ensure we don't get duplicates. I initilise `addCountry` with a value of `False`, set it to `True` after I've initialised my loop and then set to `False` again if I find that the country has already been selected. This will then continue to loop until a new country has been selected.

```
Dim countryRandom As New Random
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each rb As RadioButton In Me.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
    Dim randomNumber As Integer

    Dim addCountry As Boolean = False
    Do While addCountry = False
        randomNumber = countryRandom.Next(CountryNames.Count)
        addCountry = True
        For Each selectedCountry In selectedCountries
            If selectedCountry = randomNumber Then
                addCountry = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Loop

    rb.Text = CountryNames(randomNumber)
    selectedCountries(i) = randomNumber
    i += 1
Next
```

I then sort the `Array`:

```
Array.Sort(selectedCountries)
```

I look at getting a random number then checking to see if that random number is in the `selectedCountries` `Array`. I then use that:

```
Dim flagRandom As New Random
Dim selectedFlag As String = ""
Do While selectedFlag = ""
    Dim randomNumber As Integer = flagRandom.Next(Flagimageurl.Count)
    For Each selectedCountry In selectedCountries
        If selectedCountry = randomNumber Then
            selectedFlag = Flagimageurl(randomNumber)
        End If
    Next
Loop
flag.ImageUrl = selectedFlag
```

This should give you what you are after but I cannot stress how inefficient this code actually is.

Comment: @AlexMcIver : What you've written is highly inefficient and will require even more `If-Then-Else` statements to work. Bugs has literally given you the most simple answer to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to replace all your `If` statements with the 3 loops below - not the best way of doing it, but for the purposes of your program, it won't impact performance much.

The code checks that buttons 2,3 and 4 are not the same as any other. You dont need to check button 1 because the loops will check that all of the subsequent buttons aren't the same as it.

Each loop will choose a new random text string from your array. If it is the same as any of the other buttons, it will choose another one until it is different to all of them.

```
    Do While RadioButton2.Text = RadioButton1.Text Or RadioButton2.Text = RadioButton3.Text Or RadioButton2.Text = RadioButton4.Text  'Makes sure that the radiobuttons don't show duplicate answers'
        RadioButton1.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())
    Loop
    Do While RadioButton3.Text = RadioButton2.Text Or RadioButton3.Text = RadioButton1.Text Or RadioButton3.Text = RadioButton4.Text  'Makes sure that the radiobuttons don't show duplicate answers'
        RadioButton1.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())
    Loop
    Do While RadioButton4.Text = RadioButton2.Text Or RadioButton4.Text = RadioButton3.Text Or RadioButton4.Text = RadioButton1.Text  'Makes sure that the radiobuttons don't show duplicate answers'
        RadioButton1.Text = CountryNames(5 * Rnd())
    Loop
```

However, your choice of using `Rnd()` will be very unlikely to generate the number 5. You would be better changing the above code to this

```
    Dim randomNumber As New Random

    flag.ImageUrl = Flagimageurl(randomNumber.Next(0, 5)) 'Choosing a random flag'
    RadioButton1.Text = CountryNames(randomNumber.Next(0, 5)) 'Randomly picks the country according to the CountryNames array'
    RadioButton2.Text = CountryNames(randomNumber.Next(0, 5)) 
    RadioButton3.Text = CountryNames(randomNumber.Next(0, 5))
    RadioButton4.Text = CountryNames(randomNumber.Next(0, 5))

    Do While RadioButton2.Text = RadioButton1.Text Or RadioButton2.Text = RadioButton3.Text Or RadioButton2.Text = RadioButton4.Text  'Makes sure that the radiobuttons don't show duplicate answers'
        RadioButton1.Text = CountryNames(randomNumber.Next(0, 5))
    Loop
    Do While RadioButton3.Text = RadioButton2.Text Or RadioButton3.Text = RadioButton1.Text Or RadioButton3.Text = RadioButton4.Text  'Makes sure that the radiobuttons don't show duplicate answers'
        RadioButton1.Text = CountryNames(randomNumber.Next(0, 5))
    Loop
    Do While RadioButton4.Text = RadioButton2.Text Or RadioButton4.Text = RadioButton3.Text Or RadioButton4.Text = RadioButton1.Text  'Makes sure that the radiobuttons don't show duplicate answers'
        RadioButton1.Text = CountryNames(randomNumber.Next(0, 5))
    Loop
```

This code will be equally likely to generate all of the numbers.

Comment: Can you look at my updated code: https://github.com/alexmciver/Alex-M-Flags/blob/master/Default2.aspx.vb 

Where do I add your loop into my code?

Comment: I've created a fork and pull request on Git - Have a look at the comments and by all means get back to me with any queries you have about the changes